# Prove that $\int_{B^2(0,1)}||D(\Phi)||=\int_{\Phi(B^2(0,1))}||D(\Phi^{-1})||$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $\Phi:\Bbb R^2 \to \Phi(\Bbb R^2)\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ be a diffeomorphism. Prove that

$\int_{B^2(0,1)}||D(\Phi)||=\int_{\Phi(B^2(0,1))}||D(\Phi^{-1})||$,

where $||A||=(\sum_{i,j=1}^2a_{ij}^2)^{1/2}$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of the matrix and $D$ is the differential.

**I have tried in this way:**
Let us consider $I=\int_{B^2(0,1)}||D(\Phi)||$. Now substitute $\underline y=\Phi(\underline x)$ then $\underline{x}=\Phi^{-1}(\underline{y})$.

Then, $I=\int_{\Phi(B^2(0,1))}||D(y)||Jacobian(D(\Phi^{-1}))$.

If I am not wrong here $D(y)$ will be the identity matrix so $||D(y)||=n$. Here I am confused again that $D(y)=(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})$, the matrix or not!

Here is my problem, is it true that $Jacobian(D(\Phi^{-1}))=\frac{1}{||D(y)||}||D(\Phi^{-1})||$? If it is true then we are done i.e.
$$I=\int_{\Phi(B^2(0,1))}||D(1)||Jacobian(D(\Phi^{-1})=\int_{\Phi(B^2(0,1))}||D(\Phi^{-1})||$$ but how to prove that portion?

Please help

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense to me. Please add lots more steps and explanations.

Comment: Actually I used the substitution, I think the problematic part is the main part that I have to prove which I can't. I don't know what to add when I am unable to figure that out.

Comment: If you won’t do as I ask, then I won't expend any energy on it.

Comment: $D$ is the differential? In that case $D\Phi (\Phi^{-1}(y)) \neq D1$, where I assume that you mean $1(x) = x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I can't actually understand what you are asking. I have tried to give you info as much as possible. If you want to know any particular thing I can try otherwise I am helpless. Thanks for trying to help me though.

Comment: @Jfischer I have edited. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. You can't get rid of $D\Phi$ merely by changing variables. And, also, for the record, the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of the identity is $\sqrt n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are trying to take cannot work, as the result depends entirely on dimension $2$; indeed, you can easily check that it is false for a linear map in dimensions $3$ and greater.

Here's the idea. For an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix $A$, you can check that (for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm)
$$\|A^{-1}\| = \frac1{|\det A|}\|A\|.$$
You can now verify that when $\Phi$ is an invertible linear map, the result holds. Now do the usual game of chopping the domain into small pieces (on which $\Phi(x)=\Phi(x_0)+D\Phi(x_0)(x-x_0)+\varepsilon$) and approximating the integral. (Of course, you will also need to use the chain rule fact that $D\Phi^{-1}(\Phi(x)) = \big(D\Phi(x)\big)^{-1}$.)

Answer (score 1):

By the Inverse Function Theorem, as $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism we have that $D\Phi^{-1}(\Phi(x,y)) = (D\Phi(x,y))^{-1}$. Using this and the fact given by Ted Shifrin that for a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$, under the Hilbert Schmidt norm,
$$||A^{-1}|| = \frac{1}{|\text{det}A|} ||A||$$
we can see that,
$$||D\Phi^{-1}(\Phi(x,y))|| = ||(D\Phi(x,y))^{-1}|| = \frac{1}{|J_\Phi(x,y)|}||D\Phi(x,y)|| $$ which of course implies that $|J_\Phi(x,y)| \cdot||D\Phi^{-1}(\Phi(x,y))|| = ||D\Phi(x,y)||$
Thus by the Change of Variables formula,
$$\int_{\Phi(B^2(0,1))} ||D\Phi^{-1}(x,y)|| = \int_{B^2(0,1)}|J_\Phi(x,y)|\cdot||D\Phi^{-1}(\Phi(x,y))|| = \int_{B^2(0,1)} ||D\Phi(x,y)|| $$